# getting error : Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type. when querying again DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am getting an error when trying to insert into a table. As the error shows I know is because of the smalldatetime field. But I have tried several different things From other posts and its not working. Plus when I'm reading from the same table I use the same format for smalldatetime and it works. code show below. Any help would be really appreciated.

Code when trying to Insert a new row
.vb.net

```
Dim conn As String = "Your Connection String"
    'Dim querystring As String = "INSERT INTO  'Where SupID='" & supervisor & "' Order By EmpNum"
    Dim querystring As String = "INSERT INTO [AttendanceDB].[dbo].[tblAbsences]([fldEmployeeID] " & _
                                ",[fldAbsentDate],[fldAbsentCode],[fldRuleViolationWarningType],[fldRuleViolationIssueDate] " & _
                                 ",[fldLOAEndDate]) VALUES('23','11-06-2014','NA','NULL','NULL','NULL')"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(conn)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(querystring, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Try
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```

I have also tried this code in SQL Management Studio

```
INSERT INTO [AttendanceDB].[dbo].[tblAbsences]([fldEmployeeID],
        [fldAbsentDate],[fldAbsentCode],[fldRuleViolationWarningType],
        [fldRuleViolationIssueDate],[fldLOAEndDate])
VALUES     ('23','11-06-2014','NA','NULL','NULL','NULL')
```

This is the code that works when im reading from the same table when databinding to ViewGrid

```
Dim startdate As String = txtcalendarstart.Text
    Dim enddate As String = txtcalendarstop.Text
    startdate = startdate.Replace("/", "-")
    enddate = enddate.Replace("/", "-")
    Dim SqlDataSource2 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2"
    Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2)
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SVR-SQLDB2;Initial Catalog=AttendanceDB;Integrated Security=True"        
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-03-2014' AND '8-21-2014' ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID]"        
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: if the DB column is a date, pass a DateTime Type, not a string

Comment: If you pass a date as a string, use YYYY-MM-DD format.  It *almost* always works.

Comment: @Plutonix This is why I try :  Dim datetime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("11/07/2014")
        Dim querystring As String = "INSERT INTO [AttendanceDB].[dbo].[tblAbsences]([fldEmployeeID] " & _
          ",[fldAbsentDate],[fldAbsentCode],[fldRuleViolationWarningType],[fldRuleViolationIssueDate] " & _
          ",[fldLOAEndDate]) VALUES('23','" & datetime & "','NA','NULL','NULL','NULL')" And it didn't work same error

Comment: `'NULL'` is a four character string and isn't convertible to a date of any kind. `NULL` is a special marker to indicate the absence of a value. (And, as per any question like this, it would be far better if you were to use parameters, which allows you to continue to use natural data types in both your code and your SQL, rather than forcibly converting to/from strings)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The NULL as Character was the problem. Thanks

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` will almost always work if you almost always work in the US. Working in the UK almost all the servers I use have a default `DATEFORMAT` of `DMY` meaning this format almost always fails, or worse, gives a different date to the intended one. The format `yyyyMMdd` is the **only** unambiguous format when working with `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME`. Otherwise you will need to specify your `DATEFORMAT` for each query, or explicitly state the style you are using - e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2014-8-21', 110)`. `YYYY-MM-DD` is fine for `DATE` and `DATETIME2`